# css style dont work and js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I try to to set up a website where you can upload files. With [this](http://hmkcode.com/spring-mvc-jquery-file-upload-multiple-dragdrop-progress/) tutorial. I set it up like they did but the css style got no effect. I use eclipse and my html file looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery File Upload Example</title>
<script src="WebContent/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
 
<script src="WebContent/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="WebContent/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<script src="WebContent/js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
 
<!-- bootstrap just to have good looking page -->
<script src="WebContent/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="WebContent/bootstrap/css/bootstrfap.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- we code these -->
<link href="WebContent/css/dropzone.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="WebContent/js/myuploadfunction.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Spring MVC - jQuery File Upload</h1>
<div style="width:500px;padding:20px">
 
    <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" data-url="rest/controller/upload" multiple>
 
    <div id="dropzone">Drop files here</div>
 
    <div id="progress">
        <div style="width: 0%;"></div>
    </div>
 
    <table id="uploaded-files">
        <tr>
            <th>File Name</th>
            <th>File Size</th>
            <th>File Type</th>
            <th>Download</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
 
</div>
</body> 
</html>
```

The path to the css and js files should be right. I draged and droped them into it. I read that you have to clear the cache from the browser. But still only the plain html site. The styles are not loaded what I can see in the browser when I investigate the elements. If I write the css style in the html file. It doesnt work aswell.
I hope someone can help me.
kind regards Sam

My english is bad. Sorry for this!

Comment: does the javascript work?

Comment: No it doesnt work. I can only click on "Add files" and select a file.

Comment: so where is this file? It would have to be in the same folder as the folder called WebContent to work.

Comment: index.html is in the folder Webcontent. the other folders css,js and bootstrap are in Webcontent too.

Comment: then take the word WebContent off of each path.

Comment: the path to css and js is relative to the index.html

Comment: please make sure your js and css link are working. you can inspect element from browser and find each link and try to load each link by click. if these are not working you have to check your link

Comment: Ok now I did the following:Webcontents/css/dropzone.css-->css/dropzone.css. Still doesnt work.

Comment: Could you try "/css/dropzone.css" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works with /css/dropzone.css.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The path to your CSS and JS files states that you are linking to a relative path of `WebContent/js/` or `WebContent/css/`. Which means that you would need a folder named `WebContent` inside the same folder as your html file. I would recommend using the naming structure `web-content` or `assets` as your folder name and place your js and css folders within that.

Comment: Ok I now changed the path from Webcontents/css/dropzone.css to css/dropzone.css. But it still doesnt work

Comment: @ReasyEasyPeasy you don't want to use capitals in your folder name. Try renaming your folder web-content and change it in the links as well